# Using jQuery to manipulate a composed HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a data scraping application.  The pages I want to scrape have already been collected by server-to-server requests, and are currently stored in my database.  I use an axios request to retrieve them from my database, and I now want to traverse/manipulate the pages using my VueJS application.

Here's what I have so far...

```
import $ from 'jquery'
...
...
axios.get('/mydomain/fetch_page/1')
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data.body); // log point #1
        let $page = $(response.data.body);
        // let $heading = $page('h2');
        console.log($page); // log point #2
    })
```

At log point #1 the page looks fine.  It includes the entire page: DOCTYPE, html, head, body, etc

At log point #2, it is an object where each property represents a DOM node, including text nodes.

If I un-comment the line that queries the `$page` for a `$heading`, I get an error telling me that `$page` is not a function.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use something like a webdriver or selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$page` is a jQuery object, not a function. Just as when you're writing web applications using jQuery, you call methods on it, you don't call it as a function.

To get the `h2` elements, use the `.find()` method:

```
let $heading = $page.find("h2");
```